# Saving HTML code as its own application

Tags: javascript, html, desktop

How do I save or convert the HTML code into its own program? For example: I want to double click on the file on my desktop to open up as its own application. I don't want it to open through Notepad++ or any other program.

The best way I can explain this is: look at all of your desktop icons. When you double click something it runs on its own. It doesn't need Notepad++ or whatever coding program you used to open up first. Now implementing that exact same concept to my question. I want to open the program I have coded in it's own window.

I hope that makes sense. I don't want to show my code because it's original.

EDIT: The HTML code consists of CSS and JS. Can I open it without a browser? Example: Visual Basics you can create window applications. I was wondering if I could do the same thing except with HTML code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you mean open in a browser?

Comment: HTML files usually open in your default browser (unless you change this setting)

Comment: You can't! You always need a interpreter. HTML isn't standalone.

Comment: :( So I would have to code it in Python or Visual Basics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is not compiled into anything, and thus cannot be run independently.  It must be interpreted by a browser or other similar piece of software.

If you have written what you deem a 'program' in HTML/JavaScript, then your best bet would be to host it somewhere and bookmark the page to your desktop.  I hope this answers your question...

Comment: Thank you! Answered my question. VB or Python are standalone right?

Comment: They can be yes, what exactly are you trying to do?  E.g. What does the program do?

Comment: You drag and drop audio onto it and it runs it :P.

Comment: I will look into them. Thank you Aeaex for the help and everyone else too!

Answer (score 1):

You right click on the icon, and choose Open With: which should bring up a list of applications you can use to open that type of file.

And you can browse to the location of the program you want to use to open the file.

Hope that helps.